# No logro imprimir bien el contenido de cada uno de mis divs usando each

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este código:

```js
$(function(){
    const bloques = $('#main')
    bloques.each(()=>{
        console.log($(this).find('h1').text())
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="bloque1">
                <h1 class="titulo">SEDANS</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip</p>
            </div>
            <div id="bloque2">
                <h1 class="titulo">SUVS</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="bloque3">
                <h1 class="titulo">LUXURY</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Con *JQuery* estoy intentando acceder a los *h1* de cada *div* de mi `#main`. No sé bien cómo funciona la función *each*, pensé que era estilo *for in*, pero el punto es que me imprime en una sola línea el contenido de cada h1 de cada `<div>` hijo de `<div id="main">`.

Mi intención es que en cada iteración del objeto bloques, se imprima por consola el texto de los *h1* de cada uno de los *div* hijos del *div main*.

Lo que quiero como resultado es que se imprima:

> SEDAN
> SUVS
> LUXURY

Pero lo que imprime es:

> SEDANSUVSLUXURY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres utilizando `function()` en el `each()` en lugar de `()=>` asi:

```js
$(function(){
    const bloques = $('#main1').find("div")
    bloques.each(function(){
        console.log($(this).find('h1').text())    
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div id="main1">
            <div id="bloque1">
                <h1 class="titulo">SEDANS</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip</p>
            </div>
            <div id="bloque2">
                <h1 class="titulo">SUVS</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="bloque3">
                <h1 class="titulo">LUXURY</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas usar *find* dentro del *each*, propongo acceder al `h1` en la instancia de bloques con `#main h1`:

```
const bloques = $('#main h1');
```

Al usar `#main h1` le dices que recupere todos los `h1` que están dentro de `#main` (allí ya tienes la lista de `h1` para poder recorrerlos).

Y luego recorres todos los `h1` en el *each* y utilizando `this` accedes al texto, de esta forma te evitas utilizar el find y si te das cuenta es como utilizar un *for in* o el tradicional *foreach*, tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(function(){
    const bloques = $('#main h1');
    bloques.each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="bloque1">
            <h1 class="titulo">SEDANS</h1>
            <p class="parrafo">Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bloque2">
            <h1 class="titulo">SUVS</h1>
            <p class="parrafo">Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bloque3">
            <h1 class="titulo">LUXURY</h1>
            <p class="parrafo">Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```